# Executing a shortcode from a "normal" text/hyperlink

Tags: shortcode, links

Is it possible the executed a shortcode from a *normal* HTML?

For example:  `<a href=[shortcode]> press here</a>` and when the user clicks the text, the shortcode is called?

I
Basically I want to call elementors popup without using a freaking button, just want the users to be able to click in the text to get a pop-up with informations.

I know there are popup plugins that has that options, but "another" plug-in isn't necessary, beside no popup could be styled as good as elementor.

Comment: I you really want your pop-up plugin to just look like a link then are you able to style it like a link?  Make it inline with the content, remove all the button 'appearance' and just keep it as a button.  Or is it that you're encountering an issue where Elementor basically injects a ton of code to generate a button.  I think this is only an issue because you're using something assumptive like Elementor (and other page builders).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no

I created a shortcode named `foo`:

```php
add_shortcode( 'foo', 'fooshort' );
function fooshort( $atts ) {
    return "https://google.com";
}
```

Then put this in a post:

> test [foo]

The result:

> [test](https://google.com) https://google.com

So if I take your question literally, yes, you can put shortcodes in anchor attributes. But the shortcode has no idea it's in an attribute. The shortcode could generate output that completely breaks the tag, and maybe even the page from that point onwards.

**However**

Shortcodes aren't magic tokens, they literally just get replaced with their output, and **they have zero awareness of their context**. That hasn't stopped page builders abusing them to imply they can do more. They're just substitutions, a way to embed something in post content that can't be put directly in the content, like an embed code, or an iframe, etc

Because of this, you can't apply any kind of logic to them as far as functionality goes. It's highly unlikely that your hyperlink will behave the same way a button does just by putting the shortcode in the `href`. However much plugin builders might suggest or imply it, there's no framework or system that adapts. Perhaps blocks in the block editor might be able to do that, but not shortcodes.

Shortcodes are dumb, they're just substitutions of shortcodes for content. Perhaps your plugin uses some logic that works off of the URL rather than something else, fingers crossed. Eitherway you're better off asking in the Elementor community for Elementor problems.

Comment: Yeah, maybe best to ask the elementor community about this, was just interested if there was anyway to trigger the shortcode. Just because I put it in a href, didn't mean it was an address, I'm just after a clickable text that calls a shortcode, regardless what that shortcode do or displays.

Comment: I see, if my answer answers your question could you mark it as accepted?